# ssh - remotely passing and setting a variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, ssh

```
ssh xxx@remote_system " echo $dateVar; date=$dateVar"
```

I am trying to pass `dateVar` to the remote system from within the shell script, which I believe works fine and then trying to set the date on the remote server to that of the `dateVar` variable, but with no success. Can someone please help?

Regards!

Comment: I see that you're setting a variable named `date`. What effect do you expect this to have?

Comment: Does "echo" print the correct value? And you do know that you need to call the `date` command without the `=`, otherwise you're just creating a new variable named `date` without using it?

Comment: You can set the date using something like date -s "20012.01.07-22:46+0000", your approach just defines a new variable.

Comment: I am trying to set the date on the remote system to that of the local system from where I am ssh'ing. I am really new at this, so help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!!!

The $dateVar which holds the date for the local system is displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [date man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date), to set date using the `date` command you should do `date --set=$dateVar`. Therefore, in order to change date on a remote system, executing the following should suffice:

- `ssh xxx@remote_system "sudo date --set=$dateVar"`

Comment: Thanks. This should work though as stated below, I need to play around a bit with the sudoers file.

Comment: The following command worked: ssh xxsi675 sudo date --set="'$dateVar'"

Comment: @user1139654: if the command worked for you, can you set it to a correct answer by clicking the tick mark next to it to green? Also, don't forget to up-vote @DarkDust's answer as for his suggestion to use `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the date format is correct, you need to remove the `=` since it creates/sets a *variable* named `date` instead of calling the command `date`:

```
ssh xxx@remote_system "date $dateVar"
```

Your user `xxx` might not have the necessary rights, so you might set up `sudo` (google for things like `sudo` and `/etc/sudoers`) so you can do:

```
ssh xxx@remote_system "sudo date $dateVar"
```

Comment: The following command worked:

ssh xxsi675 sudo date --set="'$dateVar'"